# Что значит "деревенская ностальгия"?

Tags: словосочетания

Если ностальгия по деревне, это понятно. А в таком сочетании заложен ли другой смысл?

Comment: Откуда она, “деревенская ностальгия”, взялась? Цитатку бы.

Comment: @shampar а что для вас меняет цитата? Вопрос о принципе возможности употребления этого сочетания навыворот. Ностальгия могла бы быть юношеской, московской, детской. Суть вопроса останется, перефразирую: "какой смысл передаёт сочетание N-СКАЯ НОСТАЛЬГИЯ, может ли оно быть тождественно выражению НОСТАЛЬГИЯ ПО N?".

Comment: Цитата (для нас) меняет отношение к вопросу. У Д. Самойлова в Подённых записях есть такое сочетание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрая память о деревенском периоде жизни вполне может быть названа деревенской ностальгией. По аналогии с той же временной меркой, как и к юношеской Н., например.

> Деревенская ностальгия ― масонский знак победивших полугорожан. Внутри
>   этого законная гордость: «Вона ― кем мы были, а эвона ― кем стали».
>   (Давид Самойлов)

Answer (score 0):

Подумайте над разницей между "ностальгия по силе" и "сильная ностальгия". Если под словом "деревенская" вы будете иметь в виду "простецкая", то смысл будет уже совсем иной, как и моем примере в первом предложении. Но я, честно говоря, не встречал такого сочетания слов.

Возможно ли оно? Да, а кто запрещает? :)